# git switch branch and pull

Tags: git, version-control

My organization does not believe in merge commits. As such, we do work on `master` and cherry-pick it to typically one stable branch, which I'll name `stable` here. (We also have a single remote, `origin`, which simplifies some of the commands here).

So my current flow is as follows:

```
$ git branch
* master
  stable 
# do some work and commit it to 'master'
$ git commit -a -m "some message"
# rebase on 'origin/master' because there were commits by colleagues in the meantime
$ git fetch && git rebase origin/master
$ git push origin master
# here's the rub: switch to 'stable', which is present in the local repo and behind 'origin/stable'
$ git checkout stable
# now update (a fetch may be necessary before, depending on how busy the remote repo is), git pull would also do
$ git merge --ff-only
# cherry-pick, push etc.
$ git cherry-pick master ...
```

My issue is that switching to an existing local branch followed by an update has redundant operations: restoring outdated files. Basically, I'm going to a place just to get to another, when a direct route is possible:

```
# suppose I have pushed my changes to origin/master already
$ git branch -d stable
# some git grumbling, but origin/stable is ahead, so no commits are lost and the operation has proceeded
$ git checkout stable
```

Of course, I could make this into an alias. But I'm wondering: **is there a better way to switch to a branch and get it updated to its state on the remote?** It's also possible I'm overlooking a possible problem with my proposal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing now is fine, but if you want to force your `stable` to match your `origin/stable` *and* get onto your `stable` at the same time, use `git checkout` or `git switch` with the `-B` or `-C` option respectively, and both names.  That is:

```
git fetch                              # if needed
git checkout -B stable origin/stable
```

This is a little dangerous because it does not verify that `origin/stable` is *strictly ahead of* `stable`, i.e., that this branch resetting process will result in a fast forward.  To make sure that it will be a fast forward, while you're not on it, you can use the rather obscure sequence:

```
git push . origin/stable:stable
```

or the equivalent:

```
git fetch . origin/stable:stable
```

You can combine the latter with a `git fetch` to the remote via:

```
git fetch origin stable:stable
```

If the adjustment to your `stable` is *not* a fast forward, you'll get a rejection-due-to-non-fast-forward error.

(None of these work when the current branch *is* named `stable`; in that case, use `git merge --ff-only origin/stable` to move forward, or get an error.)

(I would recommend writing a little script to do what you'd like done, and make it handle all the various corner cases, such as inspecting your current branch name.)

Answer (score 0):

Get all changes first, including remote master branch and stable branch
`git fetch --all`

Then you can quickly reset local stable branch by the following command
`git branch -f stable origin/stable`

You can do the cherry-pick after switching the branch
`git switch stable`

From my experience, the flow you used is weird. Since you use cherry-pick to sync commits to stable branch(it will generate new commits on target branch, although they have same content), what's the meaning of the `rebase` operation on master and origin/master?
It's not recommended to use cherry-pick on long-term branch.